# Quisiera resumir esta consulta MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta MySql bastante compleja que es para realizar el cierre de caja de un negocio, primero voy a presentar las tablas que tengo para poder desarrollar la idea en orden:

**Tabla caja:**

```
CREATE TABLE `caja` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fechadecierre` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `final` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `estado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `comprobada` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dinerodecajainicial` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dinerodecajafinal` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `dineroparaproximacaja` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `terminal` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `registrodeentradadedinero` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `primerasuntocontable` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ultimoasuntocontable` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tabla contabilidad**

```
CREATE TABLE `contabilidad` (
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuotas` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `formadepago` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idgasto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `interesfinanciero` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `interesformadepago` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipodetransaccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `transaccion` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valordecuota` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valorfinal` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `idgasto` (`idgasto`),
    INDEX `formadepago` (`formadepago`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `tipodetransaccion` (`tipodetransaccion`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tabla tickets**

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `anulacion` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `total` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `descuento` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `señacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `terminal` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `senacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `devolucion` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `formasdepago` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `anulacion` (`anulacion`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=47321
;
```

**Tabla ticketproductos**

```
CREATE TABLE `ticketproductos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `notadecreditoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idrubro` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `productoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `precio` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `porpeso` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `promocionid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `preciooriginal` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pesodeprecio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_2` (`id`),
    INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `idrubro` (`idrubro`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `productoid` (`productoid`),
    INDEX `anulado` (`anulado`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

El funcionamiento de la base de datos seria el siguiente: al generar una venta se genera un ticket (Registro en la tabla ticket) con el detalle , en el ticket lleva items que pueden ser Servicios o Productos, los cuales están registrados en la tabla "ticketproductos", estas se relacionan mediante la columna "ticketid" de la ultima tabla nombrada. Al realizar el pago de la venta se genera un registro en "contabilidad" en donde "transaccion" es la cantidad del dinero pagado, y en "tipodetransaccion" lleva el nombre de "pago".
En la ultima tabla nombrada, se puede observar que en "tipodetransaccion" ademas de pago puede registrarse también "gasto" alegando un gasto y "retiro" a un retiro de dinero. Y cada movimiento contable se adjudica a la venta en relación con el campo "contabilidad.ticketid" haciendo referencia a "ticket.id".
En todas las operaciones se puede realizar la anulación de la misma. Si es un ticket el que se anula, se coloca en la columna "anulacion = 1 ", y todos los ticketproductos referentes a la misma también quedan anulados por la columna "anulado = 1". En cambio en contabilidad se genera un nuevo registro con el monto anulado y la columna "anulado = 1" donde se registra la anulacion de pago, no se cambia el valor de anulado sino que se genera un nuevo registro.
La tabla "caja" hace referencia a los movimientos contables, para poder generar el resumen. Entonces "caja.primerasuntocontable" y "caja.ultimoasuntocontable" hacen referencia a "contabilidad.id" donde se pueden obtener todos los datos de la caja.
Entonces la referencia serian las siguientes.

"caja.primerasuntocontable => contabilidad.id" y "contabilidad.id =< caja.ultimoasuntocontable". Entonces "contabilidad.ticketid = ticket.id" y ticketdeproductos.ticketid = ticket.id"

Cuando se registra un gasto no se hace referencia a un ticket.id sino un "gasto.id" pero no es necesario para realizar esta consulta sql.

La consulta en cuestion es la siguiente:

```
SELECT id, registrodeentradadedinero, fechadecierre, inicio, final, dinerodecajafinal, primerasuntocontable, primerasuntocontable, (SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = empleado) as empleado, estado, dinerodecajainicial, dinerodecajafinal, dineroparaproximacaja, terminal, 
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(tickets.id) AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE anulacion = 0 AND (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totalticketvalidos, 
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(tickets.id) AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE anulacion = 1 AND (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totalticketanulados, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable) AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago'),0) AS totalenventas, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE contabilidad.anulado != 0 AND (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable) AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago'),0) AS totalenventasanulado, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN contabilidad.anulado = 0 THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN contabilidad.anulado != 0 THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END)  AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable) AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago'),0) AS totalenventasingresado, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(ticketproductos.cantidad) AS i FROM ticketproductos INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = ticketproductos.ticketid WHERE ticketproductos.anulado = 0 AND (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS cantidadproductosvendidos, 
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(tickets.id) AS i FROM tickets INNER JOIN contabilidad ON contabilidad.ticketid = tickets.id WHERE (contabilidad.id >= primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totalticketregistrados, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM contabilidad WHERE tipodetransaccion = 'pago' AND anulado = 0 AND (id >= primerasuntocontable AND id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totaldineroregistrado,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM contabilidad WHERE anulado != 0 AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago' AND (id >= primerasuntocontable AND id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totaldineroanulado, 
IFNULL((SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN (anulado != 1 AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago') OR ( anulado = 1 AND tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN (anulado = 1 AND tipodetransaccion = 'pago') OR (anulado = 0 AND tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END)) AS i FROM contabilidad WHERE (tipodetransaccion = 'pago' OR tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') AND (id >= primerasuntocontable AND id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totaldineroingresado, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM contabilidad WHERE anulado = 0 AND tipodetransaccion = 'retiro' AND (id >= primerasuntocontable AND id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totalretiros, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transaccion) AS i FROM contabilidad WHERE anulado = 0 AND tipodetransaccion = 'gasto' AND (id >= primerasuntocontable AND id <= ultimoasuntocontable)),0) AS totalgastos FROM caja WHERE id = 793
```

Los resultados de la misma es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>caja</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 57px;}
      .col0 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col1 {width: 157px;}
      .col1 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col2 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col3 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col4 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col5 {width: 110px;}
      .col5 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col6 {width: 132px;}
      .col6 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col7 {width: 132px;}
      .col7 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col8 {width: 82px;}
      thead .col9 {width: 61px;}
      .col9 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col10 {width: 115px;}
      .col10 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col11 {width: 110px;}
      .col11 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col12 {width: 138px;}
      .col12 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col13 {width: 107px;}
      thead .col14 {width: 109px;}
      .col14 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col15 {width: 119px;}
      .col15 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col16 {width: 95px;}
      .col16 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col17 {width: 133px;}
      .col17 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col18 {width: 142px;}
      .col18 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col19 {width: 160px;}
      .col19 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col20 {width: 130px;}
      .col20 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col21 {width: 129px;}
      .col21 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col22 {width: 118px;}
      .col22 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col23 {width: 127px;}
      .col23 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col24 {width: 81px;}
      .col24 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col25 {width: 82px;}
      .col25 {text-align: right;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table caption="caja (1 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">id</th>
          <th class="col1">registrodeentradadedinero</th>
          <th class="col2">fechadecierre</th>
          <th class="col3">inicio</th>
          <th class="col4">final</th>
          <th class="col5">dinerodecajafinal</th>
          <th class="col6">primerasuntocontable</th>
          <th class="col7">primerasuntocontable</th>
          <th class="col8">empleado</th>
          <th class="col9">estado</th>
          <th class="col10">dinerodecajainicial</th>
          <th class="col11">dinerodecajafinal</th>
          <th class="col12">dineroparaproximacaja</th>
          <th class="col13">terminal</th>
          <th class="col14">totalticketvalidos</th>
          <th class="col15">totalticketanulados</th>
          <th class="col16">totalenventas</th>
          <th class="col17">totalenventasanulado</th>
          <th class="col18">totalenventasingresado</th>
          <th class="col19">cantidadproductosvendidos</th>
          <th class="col20">totalticketregistrados</th>
          <th class="col21">totaldineroregistrado</th>
          <th class="col22">totaldineroanulado</th>
          <th class="col23">totaldineroingresado</th>
          <th class="col24">totalretiros</th>
          <th class="col25">totalgastos</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">793</td>
          <td class="col1">1</td>
          <td class="col2">2018-09-22 20:39:07</td>
          <td class="col3">2018-09-22 17:26:18</td>
          <td class="col4">2018-09-22 19:59:19</td>
          <td class="col5">1060,00</td>
          <td class="col6">73932</td>
          <td class="col7">73932</td>
          <td class="col8">MANUELA</td>
          <td class="col9">1</td>
          <td class="col10">600,00</td>
          <td class="col11">1060,00</td>
          <td class="col12">600,00</td>
          <td class="col13">root@localhost</td>
          <td class="col14">16</td>
          <td class="col15">0</td>
          <td class="col16">1820,00</td>
          <td class="col17">0,00</td>
          <td class="col18">1820,00</td>
          <td class="col19">29,00</td>
          <td class="col20">16</td>
          <td class="col21">1820,00</td>
          <td class="col22">0,00</td>
          <td class="col23">455,00</td>
          <td class="col24">0,00</td>
          <td class="col25">1365,00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
      <em>generated 2018-09-26 10:14:06      by <a href="https://www.heidisql.com/">HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196</a></em>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

La consulta obtiene la caja 793 como ejemplo. Funciona correctamente pero es demaciado compleja, la idea es que no devuelva ningun NULL y genere los datos en general.
Intente resumirla de la siguiente manera pero no da bien.

```
SELECT caja.id, caja.registrodeentradadedinero, caja.fechadecierre, caja.inicio, caja.final, caja.dinerodecajafinal, caja.primerasuntocontable, caja.primerasuntocontable, (SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = caja.empleado) as empleado, caja.estado, caja.dinerodecajainicial, caja.dinerodecajafinal, caja.dineroparaproximacaja, caja.terminal, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tickets.anulacion = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalticketvalidos, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tickets.anulacion != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalticketanulados, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(tickets.total)),0) AS totalenventas, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN contabilidad.anulado != 0 THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalenventasanulado, 
IFNULL((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(tickets.total) - SUM(CASE WHEN contabilidad.anulado != 0 THEN transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalenventasingresado, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(ticketproductos.cantidad)),0) AS cantidadproductosvendidos, 
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(tickets.id)),0) AS totalticketregistrados, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'pago' AND contabilidad.anulado = 0) THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totaldineroregistrado,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.anulado = 1 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'pago') THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totaldineroanulado, 
IFNULL((SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'pago') OR ( contabilidad.anulado != 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.anulado != 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'pago') OR (contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END))),0) AS totaldineroingresado, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'retiro') THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalretiros, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND contabilidad.tipodetransaccion = 'gasto') THEN contabilidad.transaccion ELSE 0 END)),0) AS totalgastos FROM caja, contabilidad, tickets, ticketproductos WHERE tickets.id = ticketproductos.ticketid AND tickets.id = contabilidad.ticketid AND (contabilidad.id >= caja.primerasuntocontable AND contabilidad.id <= caja.ultimoasuntocontable) AND caja.id = 793 ;
```

Y los resultados que estan mal son los siguiente

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>caja</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 57px;}
      .col0 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col1 {width: 157px;}
      .col1 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col2 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col3 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col4 {width: 138px;}
      thead .col5 {width: 110px;}
      .col5 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col6 {width: 132px;}
      .col6 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col7 {width: 132px;}
      .col7 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col8 {width: 82px;}
      thead .col9 {width: 61px;}
      .col9 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col10 {width: 115px;}
      .col10 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col11 {width: 110px;}
      .col11 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col12 {width: 138px;}
      .col12 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col13 {width: 107px;}
      thead .col14 {width: 109px;}
      .col14 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col15 {width: 119px;}
      .col15 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col16 {width: 95px;}
      .col16 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col17 {width: 133px;}
      .col17 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col18 {width: 142px;}
      .col18 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col19 {width: 160px;}
      .col19 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col20 {width: 130px;}
      .col20 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col21 {width: 129px;}
      .col21 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col22 {width: 118px;}
      .col22 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col23 {width: 127px;}
      .col23 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col24 {width: 81px;}
      .col24 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col25 {width: 82px;}
      .col25 {text-align: right;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table caption="caja (1 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">id</th>
          <th class="col1">registrodeentradadedinero</th>
          <th class="col2">fechadecierre</th>
          <th class="col3">inicio</th>
          <th class="col4">final</th>
          <th class="col5">dinerodecajafinal</th>
          <th class="col6">primerasuntocontable</th>
          <th class="col7">primerasuntocontable</th>
          <th class="col8">empleado</th>
          <th class="col9">estado</th>
          <th class="col10">dinerodecajainicial</th>
          <th class="col11">dinerodecajafinal</th>
          <th class="col12">dineroparaproximacaja</th>
          <th class="col13">terminal</th>
          <th class="col14">totalticketvalidos</th>
          <th class="col15">totalticketanulados</th>
          <th class="col16">totalenventas</th>
          <th class="col17">totalenventasanulado</th>
          <th class="col18">totalenventasingresado</th>
          <th class="col19">cantidadproductosvendidos</th>
          <th class="col20">totalticketregistrados</th>
          <th class="col21">totaldineroregistrado</th>
          <th class="col22">totaldineroanulado</th>
          <th class="col23">totaldineroingresado</th>
          <th class="col24">totalretiros</th>
          <th class="col25">totalgastos</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">793</td>
          <td class="col1">1</td>
          <td class="col2">2018-09-22 20:39:07</td>
          <td class="col3">2018-09-22 17:26:18</td>
          <td class="col4">2018-09-22 19:59:19</td>
          <td class="col5">1060,00</td>
          <td class="col6">73932</td>
          <td class="col7">73932</td>
          <td class="col8">MANUELA</td>
          <td class="col9">1</td>
          <td class="col10">600,00</td>
          <td class="col11">1060,00</td>
          <td class="col12">600,00</td>
          <td class="col13">root@localhost</td>
          <td class="col14">28</td>
          <td class="col15">0</td>
          <td class="col16">4205,00</td>
          <td class="col17">0,00</td>
          <td class="col18">4205,00</td>
          <td class="col19">29,00</td>
          <td class="col20">28</td>
          <td class="col21">4205,00</td>
          <td class="col22">0,00</td>
          <td class="col23">4205,00</td>
          <td class="col24">0,00</td>
          <td class="col25">0,00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
      <em>generated 2018-09-26 10:10:28      by <a href="https://www.heidisql.com/">HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196</a></em>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Mi teoría es que esta mal en la parte de "INNER JOIN" donde los datos que regresan son repetidos, esto sucede en la ultima consulta, por ejemplo el total de las ventas se repite dos veces, es decir se suma por dos las ventas, alguien tendría el tiempo para decirme donde se encuentra el error? muchas gracias!

Comment: Que es lo que estas tratando de mostrar, en palabras simples, por pantalla...

Comment: La caja del día, cierre de caja

Comment: Y entonces porque dices que es compleja? que quiere decir que es compleja? es un cierre de caja, no va a ser trivial, y puede llegar hasta a tardar bastante...

Comment: acabo de re editar la pregunta, el problema es que en la ultima consulta citada, que es la que intente hacer de resumen, sale mal. Y quiero que de bien